# Copying data from worksheet to another workbook by looping through all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This is a plea to all the VBA kings out there. Given your VBA knowledge I am quite hopeful that you might be able to help me out. I will try to explain my problem as clear as possible.

**Background**: There is 1 'source file' (which is overwritten everyday with new data as part of a batching proces) with a static file name. And there is 1 'master file'. In this masterfile the first 3(but this could expand in the future) sheets are summary sheets, which will display selected tables/charts from data that is in sheet 4 - sheet N (last sheet) of the master file.

**Objective**: Copy all the data from each sheet in the source file to a defined (probably by name) sheet in the 'master file'. This means that sheet 4 till sheet N in the masterfile will get overwritten with the new data. The references in Sheet 1-3 (summary sheets) in the masterfile should then automatically update the tables/graphs.

Below a description of the steps (I think):

*'open masterfile

'run macro (button)*

*Macro:

'Open sourcefile

'Select all cells sheet 1 and copy

'Go back to masterfile and paste selection in sheet 4

'Repeat this till the last sheet in the sourcefile 
'Save sourcefile and close

'Save masterfile*

From the look of it, it does not seem like a difficult macro, but I'm quite the noob. Also, do you think this is a good way of trying to achieve the objective, or are there other more efficient/stable ways?

If anything is not clear please let me know and I will try my best to clarify.

Comment: Try using the record macro function to get you started. We are here to help you with your existing code, not write it for you from scratch.

Comment: @braX That's how I started, and it worked, but not the looping through the sheets part. I will post my code next time I ask a question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Open sourcefile
     set wb =  Workbooks(sourcefile).open
'Select all cells sheet 1 and copy,'Go back to masterfile and paste selection in sheet 4
       for each ws in wb.worksheets
          ws.usedrange.copy thisworkbook.worksheets(ws.index+3).range("a1")
'Repeat this till the last sheet in the sourcefile 
          next ws
'Save sourcefile and close
        wb.close true
'Save masterfile
         thisworkbook.save
```